# ¿Cómo puedo medir el tiempo que se demora en ejecutar un algoritmo BubbleSort en java?

Tags: java, ordenamiento

quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar con una duda que tengo para poder medir el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse un ordenamiento burbuja. En mi caso tengo listo el código solo que no se donde implementar el contador para que me muestre cuanto se demoró (en milisegundos) en ordenar el arreglo D: tengo una clase que ordena y otra test para que me muestre que se ordeno el arreglo como pueden ver a continuación:

```
public class Burbuja{
    public int[] BubbleSort(int[] arreglo)
    {
        int aux;
        for (int i=0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=i+1; j < arreglo.length; j++)
            {
                if (arreglo[j] < arreglo [i])
                { 
                    aux=arreglo[i];
                    arreglo[i]=arreglo[j];
                    arreglo[j]=aux;
                }
            }
        }

        return arreglo;
    }   
}
```

y esto seria el test:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] arreglo= {2, 4, 7, 13, 9, 27, 6, 25, 11, 18, 1, 8};
        System.out.println("Arreglo antes de ser ordenado: ");

        for(int i=0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("[" + arreglo[i]+"]");
        }
        Burbuja o=new Burbuja();
        o.BubbleSort(arreglo);
        System.out.println("\nArreglo ordenado: ");

        for (int i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("[" + arreglo[i]+"]");
        }

    }

}
```

De antemano gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El método `System.currentTimeMillis()` devuelve la hora actual en milisegundos.

Sin embargo, para medir la ejecución de un código (que puede ocurrir en menos de 1 milisegundo), se debe utilizar `System.nanoTime()`, que mide con precisión de nanosegundos.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    // ...
    // El resto del código

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    return (endTime-startTime);

}
```

Comment: Esta forma es muy inocente de medir tiempo de algoritmos en Java. Principalmente porque el JIT no se ha disparado, y el JIT incrementa mucho el tiempo de ejecución del bytecode. Con una sola muestra no se puede medir el tiempo del algoritmo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!